# IF clause giving only value of last IF condition

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following IF condition but it is always giving me the last $genreid **6000**

```
if ($URL == "/apps.html"
    or "/apps/all-genres.html"
    or "/apps/all-genres/top-paid-apps.html"
    or "/apps/all-genres/top-free-apps.html"
) {
    $genreid = "36";
}

if ($URL == "/apps/business.html"
    or "/apps/business/top-paid-apps.html"
    or "/apps/business/top-free-apps.html"
) {
    $genreid = "6000";
}
```

Could anybody help me correct this?

Comment: I don't think so. Provide more details. What does $URL contains etc? Build a test scenario. We are no diviners. And please show some effort!

Comment: Just curious is this your normal code indentation style? I realize everyone has their own but this would drive me bonkers!

Comment: `if (a == "cat" or "dog" or "elephant")` does **not** do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-empty (and non-"0") string evaluates to "true".  Your code should look more like this:

```
if ($URL == "/apps.html"
    or $URL == "/apps/all-genres.html"
    or $URL == "/apps/all-genres/top-paid-apps.html"
    or $URL == "/apps/all-genres/top-free-apps.html") {
        $genreid = "36";
}
```

Comment: *‘A non-empty string evaluates to “true”.’* No, this is PHP, remember? `if("0") { echo "Nope"; }`

Comment: @minitech - You are right...forgot "0".  Fixed my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Your ors are all screwed up.  The OR "foo" is just going to resolve to true.

Try something like this:

```
if (in_array($URL,array('test1','test2','test3') ))
{
    $genreid = "36";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($URL == "/apps/business.html"
            or "/apps/business/top-paid-apps.html"
            or "/apps/business/top-free-apps.html"
            )
```

This checks whether *one of the following is truthy*:

- `$URL` is `"/apps/business.html"`
- `"/apps/business/top-paid-apps.html"`
- `"/apps/business/top-free-apps.html"`

Those two strings are truthy, and that’s not how the `or` operator works. Compare `$URL` to each of them in turn, or use an array:

```
if(in_array($URL, ['/apps/business.html', …])) {
    …
}
```

But that’s not to mention — why aren’t you using `elseif` in the first place?

Comment: Should note that the `[]` array notation is only supported as of PHP 5.4